# Powershell Script to list all Domain connected hosts

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm busy writing a script as a project to Audit Windows Servers for PCI compliance, One of the things my project lead has asked me to attempt to get to try to get a list of all hosts that are connected to a domain, however this script needs to be able to be run on any windows server without being able to import any modules, so I'm stuck with whatever tool already exists on a bare machine.

Ive already written parts of the script that can rely on the 'active directory' modules but I also need to find a way to get information without any DNS or Domain roles installed.
The closest I can get to achieving this is by using the 'netdom' command however this relies on usernames and passwords that I cannot query for in the auditing script.

Ive tried tools like nslookup and a few other things I've come across while looking for answers online, but most of it seems to rely on modules that I cannot install on the machines that the script will need to run on.

Does anyone know if this can actually be done? and if so how can I achieve this?

Edit: for a bit more clarity, I need a way to get a list of all machines in the domain from machines that are NOT a domain controller and I cannot alter these machines at all.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing.  Just to be clear, you _can_ query AD, but only if you don't have to install add-ons like the PowerShell AD module, right?  If so, then you should take a look at the [ADSI Acceleratior](https://lazywinadmin.com/2013/10/powershell-get-domaincomputer-adsi.html) or [.NET DirectoryServices classes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-directorysearcher-net-class-and-powershell-to-search-active-directory/)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I can query ad on some servers( like domain controllers ), but not all, so my script checks for the modules before it uses them, but in the event that I don't have the modules I need to use other tools, preferably the ones that are installed on windows from the start

Comment: @Matt - please re-read the comment by `boxdog` [*grin*] ,,, it gives you the way to do this via builtin resources - `[ADSI]`.

Comment: Yeah I've been reading through the links and testing them out, while trying to work out exactly how they work. They work on my Test DC just fine, but they don't seem to want to work at all on my other machines that are connected to the Domain, for instance when I run "([adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer").findall()" I get errors stating that the domain could not be contacted or doesn't exist, I then found that the system.directoryservices.directorysearcher don't have a 'searchroot' or 'filter' defined, so I'm busy trying to figure out how to get around that at the moment

Comment: Thanks for your potential solution above, however it looks like the command needs to be actively authenticated with the domain, as when I have set the searchroot and filters correctly the command still fails to work, so unfortunately this wont work as a solution for non domain controller machines

Comment: Is the computer you're running the script from definitely in the domain - is it a member server or standalone?  Because, if it's a member server, `([adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer").findall()` should just work.  If it's not working I think you might have other problems and it'd be worth a trawl through the event log.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to close this question the adsisearcher did end up working, there was something weird going on with my lab machines where it wasn't working for the local admin but it was working just fine for the domain admin, hopefully this command will work fine in a real world test, I don't see why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per boxdog's comment "([adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer").findall()" command works just fine